# Problems with authentication and getting data to word addin with the help of office-js-helpers =)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins

Trying out office-js-helpers instead of ADAL to authenticate and fetching data. I have followed instructions from github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers and other similar questions here at stackoverflow.

This is the code - first from Office-initialize:

```
 Office.initialize = function (reason) {

    if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) {
        return;
    }

    authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();
    // Register Microsoft endpoint by overriding default values
    authenticator.endpoints.registerAzureADAuth(
        azureADClientID, //clientId
        // baseUrl,
        'xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com',  // tenant
        {
        responseType: 'token',
        scope: 'user',
        redirectUrl: 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/'
        } 
    );
```

And the AJAX call that is connected to a button to retrieve info:

```
     function getDataFromSelection() {

    authenticator
        .authenticate(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.AzureAD)
        .then(function (token) {
            var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";

            var html = "<ul>";
            var response;
            console.log("token: ", token);
            // app.showNotification("token: ", JSON.stringify(token));
            $.ajax({
                // beforeSend: function (request) {
                //    request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                // },
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.access_token,
                }
            }).done(function (response) {

                html += getPropertyHtml("Namn", response.displayName);
                html += getPropertyHtml("Titel", response.jobTitle);
                html += getPropertyHtml("Avdelning", response.officeLocation);
                // html += getPropertyHtml("Telefon jobb", response.businessPhones);
                $("#results").html(html);    
            }).fail(function (response) {
                app.showNotification('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                app.showNotification('Inloggningen slutade att fungera!', 'Du får logga ut och prova att logga in igen'); //response.responseText
                }).always(function () {

                console.log("AJAX is done!!");
                }).then(function (response) {
                    postDataToContentControlers(response);
                })
        });


}
```

Getting different errors regarding webbrowser:

Google Chrome:

I click the button and then get asked to approve to open a new window. I aprove it and it opens dialogwindow and goes to first login.microsoftonline.com and the to the addin, and then Closes the window. I get the data but in console I get errors:
[image: postMessageError]

I have included a function to be exetuced when I hit the button to populate contentControls called postDataToContentControlers(response);

Have to klick it twise to  populate contencControls. At first klick I get this error:

[image: ContentControl._onAccess]

Seems to be an Async-problem?

SOLVED: Well this was quiet simple to solve. Just moved the function into
$(document.ready(function() {}

Well on to the next webbrowser - Egde.

Here we get the same procedure as chrome exept that it doesnt Close the dialog and I don't get any data.

EDIT: This is still an isue but on older EDGE versions it is NOT an issue.

Microsoft edge 20.10240.16384.0

On that version it actually close the dialog and returns to addin were you now is logged in and retrieves the data.
Run by virtualBox were I have a Windows10 with an older edge =)

On desktop Word it works as expected =)

ON Explorer 11 similar problem as on edge

Is there anyone that have had similar problems or recognize some of it?
Hope to get some answers - thanks =)

I'm actually working on a special login page to redirect to that then close the dialog. Good or not? How to do?